# signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)

Tags: android, kotlin

Suddenly these types of error started appearing on all devices, on all android versions in my developers console.

I have checked these answers and did not find a fix for this error:

[Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x00000000 (code=2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077791/fatal-signal-7-sigbus-at-0x00000000-code-2)

[What's exactly meaning of "Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x5937abd0 (code=2)" on Android platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656263/whats-exactly-meaning-of-fatal-signal-7-sigbus-at-0x5937abd0-code-2-on-an)

[Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x8e020c98](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751555/fatal-signal-7-sigbus-code-2-fault-addr-0x8e020c98)

[Catch native crash: signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744298/catch-native-crash-signal-7-sigbus-code-2-bus-adrerr)

[Android 5.1 crash -- glDrawArrays GL_POINTS -- Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840516/android-5-1-crash-gldrawarrays-gl-points-fatal-signal-7-sigbus-code-2)

[android using Renderscript for blur effect crashes causes A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2, fault addr 0x9e6fa000 in tid 482 (AsyncTask #1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31495455/android-using-renderscript-for-blur-effect-crashes-causes-a-libc-fatal-signal-7)

[App random crashes with Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 or Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36507316/app-random-crashes-with-fatal-signal-7-sigbus-code-2-or-fatal-signal-11-sigs)

and others.

I am not using NDK.

Here are the traces:

```
signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)
memcpy
#00  pc 000000000001ae6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+356)
#01  pc 0000000000105bd4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
#02  pc 0000000001abeab0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCopyPixelsToBuffer+156)
#03  pc 0000000001ac0a88  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer+468)
#04  pc 00000000000218b0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)

signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)
memcpy
#00  pc 000000000001c3ac  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+356)
#01  pc 00000000000eff3c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
#02  pc 0000000002b7034c  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat

signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)
__memcpy_base
#00  pc 0000000000016afc  /system/lib/libc.so (__memcpy_base+104)
#01  pc 000000000008f8ff  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#02  pc 000000000242b859  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat

signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 2 (BUS_ADRERR)
memcpy
#00  pc 000000000001abec  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+356)
#01  pc 000000000011104c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
#02  pc 0000000075aa04a0  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-framework.oat
```

I have completely no idea where this is coming from. I have been searching all over the internet for the last week and found no fixes for these errors.

Could this be somehow connected to use of Kotlin in my app?

Comment: I have similar reports but I'm not using Kotlin so I think it's not correlated to it. In my case, it only affects 7.1 and mostly Motorola devices. (I just noticed you linked my question above there)

Comment: Maybe you are not using ndk, but some library in your dependencies do? Anyhow that looks like memory issues related to native code, not Kotlin

Comment: the problems where because i was trying to use the removable sd card as additional RAM for my app, and on devices with no external sd card this occured.

Comment: @lxknvlk I am getting this type of issue but in my case When I run from my second pc It's get crash and show error on nougat 7 and up devices ,When I run from other pc It's works fine. so ,out of my 7 pc only 1 pc work perfectly I can't understand It's problem of my pc or code.

Comment: @bdevloper probably that pc with error has a broken ram memory or something like that

Comment: @lxknvlk I don't think there is an issue with ram.
check It my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56816843/native-library-crash-issue-in-android-oreo-8-and-above) here

Answer (score 0):

This is because of you have not passed the proper value to the function. OpenGL must required a proper passing.

Check the samples at this link https://github.com/NativeCodeSamples/native-app-samples

Using a GL_POINTS you can draw a point or a line based on given value.

Comment: but i am not using opengl and i am not using ndk

Answer (score 0):

Clearing space in root directory helped me